Pass another parameter to "List Subversion tags" as "Repository URL" field
We are using Jenkins 2.452.1 and Jenkins Subversion Plugin 1256.vee91953217b_6 (info).
We have a Jenkins pipeline which consists of 3 parameters:

APPLICATION (type: choice parameter)

It contains a static list of 3 applications



REPOSITORY_URL (type: active choices reactive parameter)

It returns a repository URL based on the application selected in the previous parameter



SVN_TAG (type: List Subversion tags (and more))

It should show all tags from the repository URL calculated by the previous step
It shows 2 warnings:

This repository URL is parameterized, syntax validation skipped
The repository URL is parameterized, connection check skipped






When I save the job and go to "Build with parameters page", the following error is shown for the SVN_TAG parameter:

If I navigate manually to https://source.company.com/svn/C#/Application1, I can see the contents normally.
Jenkins logs show the following exception:
May 17, 2024 12:58:47 PM SEVERE hudson.scm.listtagsparameter.ListSubversionTagsParameterDefinition getTags
An SVN exception occurred while listing the directory entries at ${REPOSITORY_URL}
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E125002: Malformed URL '${REPOSITORY_URL}'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:70)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:57)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNURL.<init>(SVNURL.java:227)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(SVNURL.java:109)
    at hudson.scm.listtagsparameter.ListSubversionTagsParameterDefinition.getTags(ListSubversionTagsParameterDefinition.java:195)
    at hudson.scm.listtagsparameter.ListSubversionTagsParameterDefinition$DescriptorImpl.doFillTagItems(ListSubversionTagsParameterDefinition.java:432)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:733)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:397)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:409)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:207)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:140)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:558)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:770)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:900)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:289)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:770)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:900)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:289)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:770)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:900)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:698)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:248)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1665)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:248)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.ResourceCacheControl.doFilter(ResourceCacheControl.java:134)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.auth.jwt.impl.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:60)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215)
    at net.bull.javamelody.PluginMonitoringFilter.doFilter(PluginMonitoringFilter.java:88)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.monitoring.HudsonMonitoringFilter.doFilter(HudsonMonitoringFilter.java:121)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
    at jenkins.metrics.impl.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
    at jenkins.util.HttpServletFilter$1.doFilter(HttpServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at jenkins.ErrorAttributeFilter.doFilter(ErrorAttributeFilter.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:94)
    at jenkins.security.AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.java:52)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:54)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:101)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:97)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:63)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:111)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1580)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$RequestDispatchable.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:1598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.run(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:969)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1194)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1149)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

I suspect that the problem lies in parametrization of SVN_TAG parameter (where REPOSITOY_URL parameter is passed as one of its inputs). If I don't pass REPOSITOY_URL to SVN_TAG and instead specify an URL directly, it works normally. Is the syntax ${REPOSITOY_URL} correct?

It doesn't look like what you are trying to do is possible.
The Subversion plugin doesn't appear to expand variables the same way, say, the Git plugin does. See this call
public static String getParameterString(@CheckForNull String original, @NonNull EnvVars env) {
    return env.expand(original);
}
...
getParameterString(remoteRepository.getURIs().get(0).toPrivateString(), env),

It's ironic that they have form validation that recognizes parameterized URLs.
